# which .htaccess file should i change in pyroCMS?

Tags: php, .htaccess, pyrocms

With pyro i have two .htaccess files. One in the codeigniter folder and another one in system/cms/config. Am i supposed to have two and which one do i have to change to remove the index.php from my url? I tried the instructions on this page https://www.pyrocms.com/documentation/2.0/getting-started/removing-index-php, but no success.

My main concern is getting rid of the /index.php from my url.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly modify the .htaccess files if you know what you are doing, and there a lot of advantages to doing so, in fact the .htaccess file that comes with pyrocms gives you lots of advice on how to do so.

However, you need to make sure that you have allowoverwride and mod_rewrite enabled and set up correctly on your server. Once that is done and you change

`$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`

to

`$config['index_page'] = '';`

in system/cms/config/config.php the /index.php/ should go away (you will want to manually clear the site cache under maintenance in the admin to refresh all the links throughout your site.

Once that is done if you want to make changes for any reason ( i.e. redirect all www.example.com to example.com ), edit the .htaccess in the root of your site directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you followed the instructions as the where presented then you should be good. Another possible culprit of this might be the you web server may not be looking at .htaccess files at all.

Answer (score 0):

There's a guide here:
http://docs.pyrocms.com/2.1/manual/setup/removing-indexphp-from-urls

You can ignore /system/codeigniter/.htaccess - PyroCMS is ([for now](https://www.pyrocms.com/blog/2012/11/foundations-for-our-future)) built on top of [Codeigniter](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter) and it's just there as a precaution to prevent the CodeIgniter directory contents being exposed by mistake. Modify the one in your PyroCMS root directory (the comments should help).

You also need to ensure your Apache [VirtualHost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#virtualhost) config has [AllowOverride](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride) specified, otherwise the .htaccess file will be ignored - and Apache needs to be running [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (but that's all configured within the .htaccess file, e.g. the `RewriteEngine on` directive).

Answer (score -1):

Both the .htaccess files you have mentioned should not be tampered with.

What is needed is the following:

1) Enable mod-rewrite. On ubuntu `a2enmod rewrite`
2) Keep the .htacesss file that came with the pyrocms installation. Use the latest one just to be sure and replace the old one
3) Edit system/cms/config/config.php and change: `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`

Comment: There's absolutely no harm in editing .htaccess (the PyroCMS one - in the root directory - is specifically designed you for you to easily  uncomment the sections you need, like redirects and the environment variable).  Just keep backups or use version control and don't allow other people direct access to your server. If using Git, you may need to add it to .gitignore too as you might have a different version on development and production machines.